# Error Connect a docker Instance to mongoDB atlas

Tags: mongodb, docker, go, mongodb-atlas

I made a go App conected to MongoDB Atlas and works fine when run locally, but when i tried to create docker-compose i get this error

```
error parsing uri: lookup _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.mrknb.mongodb.net on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:37379->127.0.0.11:53: i/o timeout
```

My connection string is :

```
mongodb+srv://apiVentas:<password>@cluster0.mrknb.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

My DockerFile is:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder

ENV GO111MODULE=on \
CGO_ENABLED=0 \
GOOS=linux \
GOARCH=amd64

WORKDIR /build

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go test ./...

RUN go build -o main .

WORKDIR /dist

RUN cp /build/main .

FROM scratch

COPY --from=builder /dist/main /

ENTRYPOINT ["/main"]
```

And Docker-compose is

```
version: "3"

services:
 web:
  container_name: apiVentas
  restart: always
  build: .
  ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  volumes:
    - .:/home/perajim/go/src/api.ventas
  dns:
   - 1.1.1.1
   - 1.0.0.1  
   - 8.8.8.8
```

I add my IP to list in mongoDB Atlas

It's necessary some configuration in docker?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Atlas runs on port 27017 , change the port binding and then try.